# External libraries that aren't on npm with webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

Just started using webpack and understand the basics. Although, I'm trying to use an external library and want to follow the "webpack way". Currently I use npm then require using commonjs syntax. What's the correct way for including libraries such as http://johnpolacek.github.io/imagefill.js/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this type of config:

```
resolve: {
    root: __dirname,
    alias: {
        vendors: './libs'
    }
},
entry: {
    vendor: [
        'expose?$!expose?jQuery!jquery/dist/jquery.min.js', 
        'vendors/jquery-imagefill.js'
    ]
},
```